# What is an efficient way to check whether an element in a list is unique?

Tags: java, list

What is an efficient way to check whether an element in a list is unique (no other element with the same value) in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Collections.frequency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) is useful here:

```
public static <T> boolean hasDuplicates(List<T> list, T element) {
    return Collections.frequency(list, element) > 1;
}
```

This is linear in time, so it might be slow on large lists. However, if you need to use a `List`, you cannot perform much better, at most you can take advantage of early exit to reduce *average* running time:

```
public static <T> boolean hasDuplicates(List<T> list, T element) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T other: list) {
        // Ugly, but necessary to ensure null-safety
        boolean areEquals = (other == null)? element == null : other.equals(element);
        if (areEquals) {
            count += 1;
            if (count > 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1. Did not know that one (even though it's been here since Java 5). Null-safe, too.

Comment: +1 didn't know about this method either.  A nice fit with the new streams API too.

Comment: @Thilo basically it is same as your answer.  and slower than your suggestion. because it go through the whole list.

Comment: "the best you can do": Cannot help O(n), but a custom loop could short-cut when the second element is found.

Comment: HS is there something like this even present. did not know it so removing my comment above :)

Comment: @Kent fair enough. Editing in progress :)

Answer (score -2):

To improve performance you can do as follow:

1. Convert list to set as follow:

   ```
   Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>(employeeList);
   ```
2. Now for each incoming element you can check if value returned by add method is false or true as below:

   ```
   boolean bool = employeeSet .add(dupEmployee);
   if(bool)
      // do this
   else 
     // do that
   ```

NOTE: You have to make sure to oerride `hashCode` and `equals` method in `Employee` class.

Comment: I would love to know the reason for down vote, according to me my approach is not O(n) and is superb speedy.

Comment: Not me to downvote, but since you ask: 1. this _is_ O(n) (`HashSet` construction from `List` implies a list scan, which is linear). 2. this does not even answer the question. You are checking if an element is _already_ is the list, not detecting duplicates already in the list. If you fail to recognize that, maybe you deserve that -1.

Comment: In addition to being not faster (also O(n)) it also uses up additional memory (to beuild the hash set).